# Hi, i have a problem when i try to deploy a project with a local json in vite, axios and githubpages

Tags: reactjs, json, axios, vite, github-pages

Issue with deploying a repository using local JSON: Console Error

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to deploy a repository that involves local JSON. The error in the console is as follows:
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXFdH.jpg)

However, the application works fine locally. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import styles from "../assets/scss/components/Key-Board-letters.module.scss";
import stylesDark from "../assets/scss/components/Key-Board-letters-dark.module.scss";
import axios from "axios";

function KeyBoardLetter({ usedKeys, isDark }) {
  const [letters, setLetters] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getKey();
  }, []);

  const getKey = () => {
    axios
      .get("/public/local-json/keys.json")
      .then((response) => {
        setLetters(response.data.letters);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
}
```

I'm trying to understand why this issue is happening. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please share all error messages, code etc. in text form, not as an image. If you use images, fix the markup (must begin with `![`)  so that the images become visible.